# How to fetch the data on the below mentioned condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a table named `Users`, where I have two fields `username` and `password`. Similarly, I have one more table where I have few fields and `username` field.

I have a login page where I have to check whether the `username` and `password` is present in the `Users` table, and if present, I want to fetch the data from another table corresponding to that `username`.

There can be more than one data for a single user so I have to fetch all the data for the respective user. How can I do it?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: No i have no idea how to do. But ben has replied and i will try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use subquery... effectively two queries like this

```
mysql> select * from other
    -> where name = 
    -> (select name from users where name = '<USER_NAME>' and password = '<PASSWORD>');
```

Here is an example:

```
mysql> select * from users;
+------+------+----------+
| id   | name | password |
+------+------+----------+
|    1 | one  | one      |
|    2 | two  | two      |
+------+------+----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from other;
+------+-------+
| id   | name  |
+------+-------+
|   20 | two11 |
|   10 | two   |
|   30 | two   |
+------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from other where name = (select name from users where name = 'two' and password = 'two');
+------+------+
| id   | name |
+------+------+
|   10 | two  |
|   30 | two  |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks. Exactly the one i was looking for.

Comment: @LogeshMohanasundaram cool. If this answer solved your problem, please mark it as answered by clicking on the up-tick next to this answer. [See here how](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you liked the answer, you may also up-vote by clicking on up arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries. If the user name and password match, get the user id. Then use that id to fetch the extra data after they have logged in.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking to a relational database. If you mean after a join with the "username" to the "data" table, multiple entries in the "data" table may be keyed by the same username, well that kind of answers itself, use the same key, but put different data, the DBMS should handle the rest.

If you are concerned about the uniqueness of the tuple in the data table then

CONSTRAINT tableName_a_b_pk PRIMARY KEY (a,b) where be is the discriminant of table "Data".

Answer (score 0):

```
select table2.* from table2, user where table2.username=user.username AND user.username='username' AND user.password='password'
```